Cmake , ros1 neotic (new to it)
    Performing C SOURCE FILE Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD failed with the following output:
    Change Dir: /home/yash/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
    
    Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_38f4c/fast && /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_38f4c.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_38f4c.dir/build
    make[1]: Entering directory '/home/yash/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_38f4c.dir/src.c.o
    /usr/bin/cc   -DCMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_38f4c.dir/src.c.o   -c /home/yash/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.c
    Linking C executable cmTC_38f4c
    /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_38f4c.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
    /usr/bin/cc  -DCMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD    -rdynamic CMakeFiles/cmTC_38f4c.dir/src.c.o  -o cmTC_38f4c 
    /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/cmTC_38f4c.dir/src.c.o: in function `main':
    src.c:(.text+0x46): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
    /usr/bin/ld: src.c:(.text+0x52): undefined reference to `pthread_detach'
    /usr/bin/ld: src.c:(.text+0x63): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_38f4c.dir/build.make:87: cmTC_38f4c] Error 1
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/yash/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    make: *** [Makefile:121: cmTC_38f4c/fast] Error 2
    
    
    Source file was:
    #include <pthread.h>
    
    void* test_func(void* data)
    {
      return data;
    }
    
    int main(void)
    {
      pthread_t thread;
      pthread_create(&thread, NULL, test_func, NULL);
      pthread_detach(thread);
      pthread_join(thread, NULL);
      pthread_atfork(NULL, NULL, NULL);
      pthread_exit(NULL);
    
      return 0;
    }
    
    Determining if the function pthread_create exists in the pthreads failed with the following output:
    Change Dir: /home/yash/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
    
    Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_e17fb/fast && /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_e17fb.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_e17fb.dir/build
    make[1]: Entering directory '/home/yash/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_e17fb.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o
    /usr/bin/cc   -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_e17fb.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o   -c /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CheckFunctionExists.c
    Linking C executable cmTC_e17fb
    /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_e17fb.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
    /usr/bin/cc  -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create    -rdynamic CMakeFiles/cmTC_e17fb.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o  -o cmTC_e17fb  -lpthreads 
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthreads
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_e17fb.dir/build.make:87: cmTC_e17fb] Error 1
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/yash/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    make: *** [Makefile:121: cmTC_e17fb/fast] Error 2




Performing C SOURCE FILE Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/yash/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_38f4c/fast && /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_38f4c.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_38f4c.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/yash/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_38f4c.dir/src.c.o
/usr/bin/cc   -DCMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_38f4c.dir/src.c.o   -c /home/yash/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.c
Linking C executable cmTC_38f4c
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_38f4c.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc  -DCMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD    -rdynamic CMakeFiles/cmTC_38f4c.dir/src.c.o  -o cmTC_38f4c 
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/cmTC_38f4c.dir/src.c.o: in function `main':
src.c:(.text+0x46): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
/usr/bin/ld: src.c:(.text+0x52): undefined reference to `pthread_detach'
/usr/bin/ld: src.c:(.text+0x63): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_38f4c.dir/build.make:87: cmTC_38f4c] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/yash/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make: *** [Makefile:121: cmTC_38f4c/fast] Error 2


Source file was:
#include <pthread.h>

void* test_func(void* data)
{
  return data;
}

int main(void)
{
  pthread_t thread;
  pthread_create(&thread, NULL, test_func, NULL);
  pthread_detach(thread);
  pthread_join(thread, NULL);
  pthread_atfork(NULL, NULL, NULL);
  pthread_exit(NULL);

  return 0;
}

Determining if the function pthread_create exists in the pthreads failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/yash/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_e17fb/fast && /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_e17fb.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_e17fb.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/yash/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_e17fb.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o
/usr/bin/cc   -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_e17fb.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o   -c /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CheckFunctionExists.c
Linking C executable cmTC_e17fb
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_e17fb.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc  -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create    -rdynamic CMakeFiles/cmTC_e17fb.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o  -o cmTC_e17fb  -lpthreads 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthreads
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_e17fb.dir/build.make:87: cmTC_e17fb] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/yash/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make: *** [Makefile:121: cmTC_e17fb/fast] Error 2

This is the error log , and im not able to understand wht error is and is it caused by pthreads?? im following the steps of "https://github.com/elephantrobotics/mycobot_ros" and can anyone tell wht im doing wrong related to it???? and using ubuntu 20.04 and ros neotic

I tried googling and chatgpt all i could but i couldnt understand wht is wrong as i tried to read the package.xml as well but couldnt find wht is wrong change the buildtype catkin as well got different which made me go back to the same build condition


You need yo edit your text format. It's looking very complicating. You can take a look at the other questions...
